# Why python DRMAA library (drmaa-python) can not determine status of the job submitted to SGE (UNDETERMINED) sometimes?

Tags: python, sungridengine, drmaa

I am using [drmaa-python](http://code.google.com/p/drmaa-python/) to submit and monitor jobs to and from SGE (Sun Grid Engine). I have following status in GUI

- Jobs active in Queue
- Running Jobs
- Completed Jobs
- Failed Jobs
- Status Undetermined

Sometimes I get few jobs with *Status Undetermined*. When I check jobs status using *qstat* in terminal of SGE host machine, I can see all jobs running without failing a single one. *Status Undetermined* is often misleading to users, because the user might think *Status Undetermined* jobs are having some sort of problems.

So, I understand that the problem is not with SGE, but with drmaa-python library.

Does anyone one know why drmaa-python can not determine the status?

Answer (score 2):

drmaa-python is just a thin ctype wrapper around the DRMAA C library, without any dedicated logic. For this reason, the UNDETERMINED status you see is what the SGE DRMAA C library delivers in the moment where you ask.

From what I know, it can happen from time to time that the DRMAA C library for SGE cannot fetch the status. I would recommend to add some custom retry logic in your python application to simply re-ask the scheduler.